# Django queryset : cannot F() and count at the same time

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a hard time understanding if this is a bug (most likely) in Django 1.5.2 and older, or me doing it wrong.
I wrote a queryset which uses the `F()` expression on a `DateTimeField`. This works well. However, if I call `count()` on this queryset, I get a `ValueError` with this message

```
ctypes objects containing pointers cannot be pickled
```

My query looks like this (in a method of a model Manager)

```
results = self.filter(user=user, topic__isnull=False, date__gte=F('topic__updated')).count()
```

Do you see the same kind of error on such queries ?
**Edit** : Replacing `count` with `values_list`, for example, is also an error.

Comment: Probably the model Manager instance, since the OP said the statement is inside "a method of a model Manager".

Comment: Then probably it should be `self.get_query_set().filter`

Comment: Hm, no. A manager has the same methods as a queryset. Actually this was a bug in Django 1.5.2 and older, which was fixed in Django 1.6 (with performance improvement on queryset cloning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I was doing nothing wrong. This was a bug in Django, related to `deepcopy`ing too much data when cloning querysets. This has already been fixed in Django 1.6. (the fix will also improve performance a bit)